# python file operation

Tags: python, file

please, what is the meaning of this line:

```
return [f[:f.rindex(".")] for f in os.listdir(path) if f and len(f) >= 4 and f[-2:] 

== "py" and f[-1] != "o" and f[-1] != "c"]
```

I found it in a script in this link :

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~mein/blender/plugins/python/misc/scriptloader/TheOneScript.py

I know that i needed to split the file name from its extenstion (.py) .. but why len(f)>=4

and what about f[-1] != "o" or "c" .. what this is mean ?

Comment: The meaning of that line is that the original author is a cowboy who should go back to Perl.

Comment: More seriously, len(f) >= 4 is checking that there are at least 4 characters in the file name (e.g. 'a.py' is 4 characters); f[-2:] means "the last two characters of f" and f[-1] means "the last character in f".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length check is because the shortest sensible filename is a single character followed by `.py`, which gives at least 4 characters.

The last checks seem to be trying to ingore the compiled  files with extensions `.pyc` and `.pyo`, but it's totally unnecessary as they  won't match the condition `f[-2:]  == "py"`.

For splitting a filename into a root and extension you can also consider using [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

```
[root for (root, ext) in map(os.path.splitext, os.listdir(path)) if ext == '.py']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
[f[:-3] for f in glob.iglob("*.py")]
```

as a concise alternative to the given code.

Comment: i did not understand this ,, what is the glob.iglob? i tried it and it make an error that the NameError: global name "glob" is not defined

Comment: You'd need to `import glob` first.  `glob.iglob()` only lists the files matching the pattern instead of listing all files and checking if they match the pattern later.

Answer (score 1):

This line returns all files in a directory which are at least 4 characters long, do not end with `o` or `c` but end with `py`. It cuts the remainer from the files, so `blubber.py` will be converted to `blubber`. I suggest the **following solution**:

```
[x[:-3] for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith(".py")]
```

Answer (score 0):

`f[-1]` is the last element in the iterable, in this case, the last letter of `f`

This would probably be clearer:

```
[name for name, ext in [f.rsplit('.', 1) for f in os.listdir('.')] if ext == 'py']
```

Comment: i need it to save the file name in a defined menu, but using this way the menu still empty!